# Half consonants

Tags: spacing, unicode, languages, width, alphabet

Is there a generalized code to get the half-consonants? The half-consonants are where a consonant appears cut-off from the right hand side and only about 50-75% of the consonant is visible starting from the left. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the `trimclip` package.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q3Q1.jpg     Trying to achieve this.

Comment: The corresponding unicode characters are 0915, 094D and 200D (ZWJ).

Comment: Yes, this can be achieved with `trimclip`. Example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\begin{document}
B becomes \clipbox{0ex 0ex 0.4ex 0em}{B}.
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks. But how to use the unicode numbers to achieve the same? That is, by combining the three in that order - (0x0915, 0x094D, 0x200D) - so that the resultant consonant is a half-consonant? Instead of clipping it by brute-force.

Comment: I thought latex would be using the unicode info to do this. The image file attached is a part of the pdf file which was generated using latex. Cannot ask them for the latex source file though ...

Comment: If you want to  type devanagari you should use lualatex with the HarfBuzz renderer (or xelatex) and a suitable font which supports the script.

Comment: The font file contains the instructions for the glyph behaviour; the font renderer implements the instructions: on this page, the browser renders the glyphs: क + ् = क् 
क + ् + क = क्क  

क + ् + zwj = ‍क्‍

Comment: With xelatex, you can input directly, or use unicode code points; `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\begin{document}
क + ् = क्

क + ् + क = क्क  

क + ् + zwj = ‍क्‍ 


^^^^0915^^^^094d^^^^200d

\end{document}` Your tex file must be saved in utf-8 format.

Comment: @Cicada: Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the recommendation in a comment to use Unicode directly has been accepted.

Comment: Actually, after experimenting with this, I am unable to produce everything after \begin{document} and before the carrot sign ^^^^, i.e. everything written in vernacular language. How have the three unicodes been used to get  क + ् = क्  क + ् + क = क्क    क + ् + zwj = ‍क्‍  ? Copy-pasting is not an option. Since the last one is of primary interest, how have the unicodes 0915, 094d and 200d been used in the latex document to arrive at this line ? i.e. without having any vernacular language glyphs in the tex file.

Comment: In your editor, you will need to use a font that has the characters if you want them to be visible. I use Times New Roman in my editor. To typeset the characters into the output PDF I used Noto Serif Devanagari font from Google. It is a unicode font so I had to compile with xelatex.  ^^^^0915 (or U+0915) is the codepoint for क. They are the same character, represented visually, represented numerically. Ask a separate question as it is unlikely people will be reading the comments for new questions. One question per question is the expected format.

Comment: Direct input, if that is your question: I typed क in directly (e.g. I switch language on my keyboard). Characters can also be copy-pasted in, from a Character Map, for example. There are many ways to do direct input.   If direct input cannot be used, the ^^^^xxxx method is one of many ways to do indirect input. Defining macros, setting up a mapping file, are two other ways.

Comment: Just one macro (or/and a mapping file) example please, for the क + ् + zwj = ‍क्‍  case. Direct input is not an option.